# Centering WPF Canvas on element

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to make a minimap (which is realtime updated (30+fps)) using a WPF canvas with different shapes drawn onto it. Now my problem is that each of these objects has a fixed coordinate that I cannot really change and I need the canvas to center on one of them.

Basically, I need a way to shift the canvas' origin/view. (Or a better alternative for doing something like a minimap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a translate-transformation:

```
<Canvas Height="400" Width="400" Name="MinimapCanvas">
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200"/>
  <Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
  </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

For every Update you have to calculate the exact values for the transformations - somthing like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TranslateTransform transformation;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        transformation = new TranslateTransform(0,0);
        MinimapCanvas.RenderTransform = transformation;
    }

    private void TimerTick()
    {
        //TODO: calculation
        transformation.X = 42;
        transformation.Y = 20;
    }
}
```

Edit:
In fact, I mixed two possibilities. Declaring the Transformation in xaml, and in codebehind. You can either omit the xaml part, or give your xaml-transformation an identifier via x:Name and change directly its properties...

Comment: Works perfectly, but maybe I should add that I have to transform to negative values to shift it towards my objects in positive space

Comment: So in my case it's 
                    Transform.X = -so.Position_X;
                    Transform.Y = -so.Position_Y;